# Append todays date to the results of sp_spaceUsed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To keep it simple, I'm wondering how to append a date column to the results of

```sql
exec sp_spaceUsed @oneresultset=1
```

I would like it so when it runs it has todays date/time in a "Date" Column.

If I use:

```
DECLARE @spaceUsed TABLE (
   [database_name] nvarchar(128),
   [database_size] varchar(50),
   [unallocated space] varchar(50),
   [reserved] varchar(50),
   [data] varchar(50),
   [index_size] varchar(50),
   [unused] varchar(50),
   [Date] DATETIME
)
    
INSERT INTO @spaceUsed
exec sp_spaceUsed @oneresultset=1
UPDATE @spaceUsed SET [Date] = GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM @spaceUsed
```

I get:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
> definition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: exec it into a temp table, add the extra column(s)....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're executing `sp_spaceused` for a table, here's how you do it :

```sql
USE DB;  

-- Declare a variable table
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
name VARCHAR(500),
rows BIGINT,
reserved VARCHAR(500),
data vARCHAR(500),
index_size VARCHAR(500),
unused VARCHAR(500),
today DATETIME
)
-- Insert values from SP
INSERT INTO @TEMP (name,rows,reserved,data,index_size,unused)
EXEC sp_spaceused N'NS.MY_TABLE';  
-- Add today's value  
UPDATE @TEMP SET today = GETDATE()
-- return results
SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```

The above is valid only when `sp_spaceused` is returning results for a table.

Comment: Unfortunately I need results for a DB, not 1 table. If I try to do it with a DB I get "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."